# Case Handling in SQL Query in where clause in Powerbuilder Datawindow

Tags: mysql, sql-server, join, case, powerbuilder

I have a SQL query behind a Datawindow in which i have a where clause that i want to execute based on some ind that will be passed to Datawindow as an argument. I have Multiple Table joins in the query. I know i can manipulate the where clause using case but that where clause is dependent on one of the Table joins. Is it possible that i can manipulate that Table join also using that ind. Let's say if that Ind is 'Y' include that Table join and where cluase in main query else if it's value is 'N' don't consider Table join and that where cluase in Main query.

Please see below Query :

```
 SELECT * FROM ABC, XYZ 
  WHERE XYZ.NAME = "Mark"
  AND XYZ.SURNAME = "Butcher"
```

I want that XYZ table join and its where condition should work only if my ind is 'Y' else it will simply not consider Table XYZ join and where cluase and returns result based on existing query.

Please suggest if this is do able .Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you need the same columns in either modes of your query, you could cheat by using 2 queries:

- use the general case query in the datawindow directly
- dynamically change the query from the pbscript code by accessing the `datawindow.table.select` property (you can change it with a `modify()` when you are in the second case

  ```
  my_dw.modify("datawindow.table.select='select col_1, col_n from abc, xyw where <different criteria>'")
  my_dw.retrieve()
  ```

During prototyping, you could store the result of the `modify()` in a string variable that will get an error message -if any- to help your debugging if you don't get a correct result or no result at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetSqlSelect to set the value of a datawindow's Sql statement. (There is also a GetSqlSelect to get the value.) You could use this to modify the sql in your code and then put it back into the datawindow. However, IIRC if you do this, you can't use retrieval arguments and so you'll have to build the full SQL in your code.

Answer (score 0):

The sqlpreview event of the datawindow allows you to manipulate the sql statement in nearly any way you wish as long as you return the results using the defined column names and datatypes.  You will have access to any retrieval arguments here.

Answer (score 0):

Be carefull when you change query, you must have the same number of column in your new query as in your datawindow. And that wwhen you use Modify method as when you use SetSqlSelect method.

Avoid to prepare query with "select *" and  use query where all the columns are clearly defined like in Seki's exemple.

Answer (score 0):

When a join is conditional, use the OUTER JOIN...ON syntax.

```
SELECT * FROM ABC  
  OUTER JOIN XYZ  
     ON ABC.someCol = XYZ.someCol  
    AND XYZ.NAME = "Mark"  
    AND XYZ.SURNAME = "Butcher"   
    AND :myIndicator = 'Y'
```

-Paul Horan-